# trouble while checking time in php

Tags: php, time, connection

i'm trying to make sure that all my user will not logg in during some times so I registered time of start and time of departure in mysql, When they loggin I check first if login et password is the same as in the database

if it is the same, it check if the time is ok, if not it display an errors. but for all cases it does not display the error, but it everytime logg the user on even if he is not authorized because of the wrong time.

I've written the following code:

for login:

```
 $sql='SELECT * FROM `gestionnaire` WHERE `login`="'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pseudo']).'"';
     $req=mysql_query($sql) or die;
     $data=mysql_fetch_assoc($req); 

      // si on obtient une réponse, alors l'utilisateur est un membre
      if ($data['login']==$_POST['pseudo'] AND md5($_POST['pass'])==$data['pass_md5']) { 
        if(date("H:i")<$data['depart'] OR date("H:i")>$data['depart'])
        {
             $erreur = '<font color=red>Vous n\'&ecirc;tes pas autoris&eacute; &agrave; vous connecter, revenez &agrave; '.$data['depart'].'.</font>'; 
        }

        else{
        }
         session_start(); 
         $sql="INSERT INTO `session` SET
`temps` = now(),
`login`='".$data['login']."',
`mouvement`='1'";  
mysql_query($sql) or die;

          $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id']  ;
          $users['id'] = $_SESSION['id'] ;
          $_SESSION['login'] = $data['login'];
         header('Location: GESTION/index.php'); 
         exit(); 
      } 
      // si on ne trouve aucune réponse, le visiteur s'est trompé soit dans son login, soit dans son mot de passe
      elseif ( md5($_POST['pass'])!=$data['pass_md5']) { 
         $erreur = '<font color=red>Compte non reconnu.</font>'; 
      } 
      // sinon, alors la, il y a un gros problème :)
      else { 
         $erreur = '<font color=red>Probème dans la base de données : plusieurs membres ont les mêmes identifiants de connexion.</font>'; 
      } 
   } 
   else { 
      $erreur = '<font color=red>Au moins un des champs est vide.</font>'; 
   }  
}  
}
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the 
community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See
 the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared
 statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://in3.php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you.
 If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO).
 Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Comment: What is the value of `$data['depart']`? `date('H:i')` is going to give you something like `13:57`, which is not a good string to be doing numeric comparisons on.

Comment: what is the datatype of depart column in mysql?

Comment: Dear Sir, thanks for your quick reply. Actualy I do not know any others function, do you know where can I find new functions? Kind regards

Comment: data type is time in mysql 00:00:00

Comment: yes sir, It will give to me this 16:30 so I use H:i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is with `if(date("H:i")<$data['depart'] OR date("H:i")>$data['depart'])` because php cannot do this type of comparison.

You need to convert your string time to a numerical representation, unix timestamp.

So if `$data['depart']` === '17:30' (for 5:30 pm)
You need to do something like this:

```
$today_depart = strtotime(date('Y-m-d ').$data['depart'].':00');
$time = time();
```

Now you can do `if($time < $today_depart` ...

Comment: Also, `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` can be useful for this in the query.

Answer (score 2):

Je ne comprend pas francais, but your `if` statment boils down to:

```
if {

} else {
    exit();
} else if {

} else {

}
```

Also, like Anthony indicated, PHP kind of really sucks at comparing dates. Since the start and end times are already in the database I'd suggest using `WHERE NOW() BETWEEN a AND b` or some similar construct in your query.

Comment: True, this is a problem - but there's another one with the time comparison as well.